# How to verify only the email address on user registration?

Tags: 7, users, emails

I have a registration form. On the registration form the user can enter his username, email address and password and confirm password.

When the user registered, he/she should receive an email to verify his/her email address before login to the system.

Before email verification he/she should not be allowed to login to the system.

Also he/she should set his/her password on registration, no on email verification.

Is it possible?

I am using the [logintoboggan](https://www.drupal.org/project/logintoboggan) with the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module. Through [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules), I set the status of a user to `block` upon registration. Then through rules with the event `When the user account is validated` (this event is provided by the logintoboggan rules integration module), I am activating the user.

But the problem is the loggintoboggan module automatically login the user upon email validation, which display an error message that `the user is currently not active or blocked` although the user has been actived. Because the rule event is triggered after validation of the email address.

Is there any way to prevent loggintoboggan module from automatically login the user upon email validation?

Answer (score 2):

I would NOT block the user at first. That will for sure also not cause that error message you try to get rid of. And instead use the [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module (in combination with the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module) to implement your logic like so:

- Use that same event `When the user account is validated` to flag that user with a flag labeled (say) "Validated".
- Any time you want to check if an authenticated user has been validated, you just have to verify if that "Validated" flag has been set for that user (which you can typically do with the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module also.

As a remedy to the fact that a user who registers can login to the site without email verification (as in your comment below), you can add some Rules logic like so:

- Rules Condition: if this user is not flagged (with that 'Validated' flag)
- Rules Action: perform redirect to `user/logout`

Possibly with an extra message you could set (in the same Rules Action) like "sorry, your account has not been validated yet, please do so and so first".

Comment: in this case if I not block the user. When user registers, he can able to login to site without email verification. Which I does not want.

Comment: How about you add some rules logic like (Rules Condition) "if this user is not flagged yet (with flag 'Validted')", then (Rules Action) "perform redirect to user/logout", possible with an extra message you want to set in the same Rules action like "sorry, your account has not been validated yet, please do so and so first". If that makes sense to you, I'd be happy to incorporate this comment in my answer, ok?

Comment: the problem is when I set the page redirect to user/logout, then it does not display the message. Other wise when I set the page redirect to front page then it display the message.

Comment: Not sure which message you mean, but together with the redirect you could also set whatever other message (in the same Rules Action). Or am I still missing something why you think that is not a solution for your case?

Comment: I am talking about the the message in the same rules action. Without the message the user does not know something that what happens.